# Centered and middle elements are miss aligned when other css changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've made some custom radio buttons from tow div.
Structure is

```
<div class="outer"> // for radio outer
    <div class="inner"> // for radio inner fill
    </div>
</div>
```

Css is :

```
.outer {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inner {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

It's Ok without making other changes to other elements.
Although I make adding or removing some elements which is no related by those radio button, they miss aligned.
It's not normally. Because if there are four custom radios, only one or tow or all are miss aligned.
But when zoom the web page, they are in normal.
Please explain me!
Is it caused by the browser rendering or something?

[See! It's slightly miss aligned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5rJU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Inner dot(radio select) is not position either by outer container padding or inner container margin. That's why inner dot is not centered. Here is the code

```css
.outer {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 padding:3px;
}

.inner {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <!-- // for radio outer -->
  <div class="inner">
    <!-- // for radio inner fill -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Preview at JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/phjmbg3s/

Answer (score 0):

Just add `line-height:20px` and `display:inline-block` to center the inner circle.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.outer {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align:center;
}
.inner {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"> 
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```